# Reducible to Separable First Order Differential Equation Word Problem in Analytic Geometry 1.4-28

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I completed near all problems of a differential equations text chapter on reducing non-separable first order differential equations to separable by using an appropriate substitution for example $u = y/x$ with $y' = u + u'x$ and similar substitutions in $y$ and $x$ for making other similar problems separable.

I am not asking anyone to do the entire problem for me but I do need a little guidance to begin tackling this problem. I completely understand the procedure for making them separable. What I need help in is setting up the differential equation for the following word problem. Once this is done I can easily finish the problem.

Ch 1.4-28. Find the curve $y(x)$ that passes through the point $(1, 1/2)$ and is such that at each point $(x,y)$ the intercept of the tangent on the $y$-axis is equal to $2xy^2$.

Comment: You can check what was done to make the math come out right. One needs to surround each math expression like 2xy^2 with dollar signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The differential equation:** It is convenient temporarily to let the point of tangency be $(s,t)$, and to let the curve have equation $y=f(x)$. Then the slope of the tangent line is $f'(s)$, and the equation of the tangent line is $y-f(s)=f'(s)(x-s)$. Then the $y$-intercept is $f(s)-sf'(s)$. We want this to be $2st^2$.

Now go back to $x$ and $y$. We want
$$y-x\frac{dy}{dx}=2xy^2,$$
with the appropriate initial condition.

Comment: Thank you for your input but do you know another way of setting up the diff eq without $(s,t)$ substitutions? That method is not covered in my text so it is very difficult for me to envision how it works relative to the current problem. And of course thank you for the TeX help. I get it now.

Comment: Well, we can instead rename the $x$-axis calling it the $u$-axis, and call the other axis the $v$-axis. For clarity it is helpful not to confuse the point of tangency with the variables that occur in the equation of the tangent line.

Comment: Of course now I see it. Thank you for your help.